# I have MySQL problem: ORDER BY DESC POSTS

Tags: mysql

I have one problem. I want to order by desc for posts.

```
case 'posts':
        // page header
        page_header($system['system_title'].' - '.__("Posts Directory"));

        // pager config
        require('includes/class-pager.php');
        $params['selected_page'] = ( (int) $_GET['page'] == 0) ? 1 : $_GET['page'];
        $total = $db->query("SELECT * FROM posts") or _error(SQL_ERROR);
        $params['total_items'] = $total->num_rows;
        $params['items_per_page'] = $system['max_results'];
        $params['url'] = $system['system_url'].'/directory/'.'posts'.'/%s';
        $pager = new Pager($params);
        $limit_query = $pager->getLimitSql();

        // get posts
        $rows = array();
        $get_rows = $db->query("SELECT post_id FROM posts ".$limit_query) or _error(SQL_ERROR);
        while($row = $get_rows->fetch_assoc()) {
            $row = $user->get_post($row['post_id']);
            if($row) {
                $rows[] = $row;
            }
        }
        $smarty->assign('rows', $rows);
        $smarty->assign('pager', $pager->getPager());
        break;
```

I can try order by post_id desc? Please help my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `query` statement :

```
$get_rows = $db->query("SELECT post_id FROM posts ".$limit_query) or _error(SQL_ERROR);
```

You can change to

```
$get_rows = $db->query("SELECT post_id FROM posts Order By post_id DESC".$limit_query) or _error(SQL_ERROR);
```

I am do change in `query` statement `get row post`.. Because i don't know the use for total `query` statement and the `select` statement same too. So your question about how to do `Order By Desc` for `Posts` that's what i recommended..

Comment: The `ORDER BY` should be after the `$limit_query`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this "ORDER by {field_name} DESC" to your SQL query, for example:
"SELECT * FROM posts ORDER by post_id DESC"